# CheckBox not render when using materializecss

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, materialize

I am using materialize css while using third party essentialobjects grid.My problem is checkbox is not render while rendering grid.

I found some link related to checkbox issue in materialize css.
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1376

I want to only apply fix on grid rather than whole page .Please give me your opinion

```
enter code here


<div class="row">
                                <div class="col s12 m12 l12" >

                                    <eo:Grid ID="GridGenMulti" Height="300px" Width="650px" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
                                        ColumnHeaderHeight="26" ItemHeight="50" GridLines="Both" BorderColor="#828790"
                                        GridLineColor="0, 0, 0" ColumnHeaderDividerImage="00050203" Font-Names="'Helvetica Neue', 'Lucida Grande', 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif"
                                        Font-Size="8.75pt" BorderWidth="1px" IsCallbackByMe="False" FullRowMode="false"
                                        AllowNewItem="False" ScrollBars="Auto" FixedColumnCount="1" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true"   >
                                        <ItemStyles>
                                            <eo:GridItemStyleSet >
                                                <SelectedStyle CssText="background-image: url(00050207); background-repeat: repeat-x">
                                                </SelectedStyle>
                                                <CellStyle CssText="padding-left:6px;padding-top:2px;"></CellStyle>
                                                <ItemStyle CssText="background-color: yellow; "></ItemStyle>
                                                <FixedColumnCellStyle CssText="background-color: #ebeadb;padding-left:6px;padding-top:2px; ">
                                                </FixedColumnCellStyle>
                                            </eo:GridItemStyleSet>
                                        </ItemStyles>
                                        <ColumnHeaderHoverStyle CssText="background-image:url('00050202');padding-left:8px;padding-top:2px;">
                                        </ColumnHeaderHoverStyle>
                                        <ColumnHeaderStyle CssText="background-image:url('00050201'); background-repeat:repeat;padding-left:8px;padding-top:2px;   word-wrap: break-word; vertical-align:middle;">
                                        </ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                        <FooterStyle CssText="padding-bottom:4px;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px;padding-top:2px;">
                                        </FooterStyle>
                                        <Columns>


                                            <eo:CheckBoxColumn HeaderText="Select" Visible="true" Width="100" >

                                            </eo:CheckBoxColumn>

                                            <eo:StaticColumn HeaderText="File No" Visible="false" Width="100">
                                            </eo:StaticColumn>
                                            <eo:StaticColumn HeaderText="Employee" AllowSort="true" Width="100">
                                            </eo:StaticColumn>
                                            <eo:TextBoxColumn HeaderText="Remarks" Width="350">
                                            </eo:TextBoxColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </eo:Grid>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add Text property of CheckBox to blank so it will add blank span element which has class associated to replace with original checkbox

Like for normal checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk" CssClass="bold"  Text="" runat="server" />
```

Note: Not tested for CheckBoxColumn, tested for normal Checkbox